# In Hugo, how can I select a Data file by using a front matter variable?

Tags: hugo

I want to be able to define a front matter variable in my page called `book`:

```
book: book1
```

Where `book1` is going to be a data file like this (`book1.yml`):

```
page_list:

  - cover
  - frontis
  - i
  - ii
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
etc...
```

There will be several data files like this: `book2.yml`, `book3.yml`, etc.

And then in my layout, I want to iterate over the pages, like this:

```
{{ range $page := .Site.Data.{{ .Params.book }}.page_list }}

     {{ $page }} 

{{ end }}
```

This syntax doesn't work.  Is there a way to use a front matter variable inside another variable (in my example:`.Site.Data.MY_FRONT_MATTER_VARIABLE.page_list`)?

Answer (score 1):

I found one possible solution using partials.  Basically, I move all of my HTML into a partial called "book_page" and pass in the data like this:

{{ partial "book_page"  (dict  "DATA" .Site.Data.book1  "previous_page" .Params.previous_page "current_page" .Params.current_page "next_page" .Params.next_page "depth" "" ) }}

I'm using a dictionary because I need a few other values too.  Then in the general HTML, I can access all the book1 data using .DATA.page_list, .DATA.title, .DATA.author, .DATA.side_links, etc.  I have this code in a single.html file that's the "layout" (Hugo calls them "types") for my book pages, for instance 1.md:

---

type: BookLayout1

previous_page: xiv

current_page: 1

next_page: 2

---